# How do I use command blocks to protect my spawn area?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I’m sorta newish to *Minecraft* and am now just starting to dabble with the command block.

A little background as to my goal: I’ve built a pretty big spawn area. It’s like a big fish bowl with mountains on the outside and water inside. Around the water running up to the tips of the mountains, I’ve built a massive village with castles, houses, and other large structures. I’ve spent a lot of time with it. I would like to open it up to other players, but… I want to protect the spawn. I don’t want to use addons, so that leaves me using command blocks.

My goal here is to make the spawn’s game mode adventure, and once you leave the spawn, it will change to survival. I have tried a couple different commands, but nothing seems to work the way I’d like. What I am finding is that the spawn is big. We can assume it’s around 350 blocks, give or take, from one end to another. I believe that command blocks have a range. At least from what I’ve encountered.

Some of the commands I’ve tried are

```
/gamemode a @a[r=1000]

/gamemode s @a[rm=1000]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On Minecraft Bedrock Edition, how do I make it so people can't build at spawn?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/394717/on-minecraft-bedrock-edition-how-do-i-make-it-so-people-cant-build-at-spawn)